# Process for doing payment for any product like e-commerce app in ios sdk?

Tags: ios, paypal

I am doing an iphone application which involves payment mechanism when all the time user joining in a group.

For example: I am registered user .i can create a community ,and  i can join in a community.To create and join i need to pay some money.

So,What is the best of doing payment in this scenario.
can i go for in-app purchase which apple provide? or can i go for any payment integrations methods like paypal sdk?

Which is the suitable process for doing payment every time to buy a product or to join in a community?

Here its not a feature i am buying once.it is like product i can buy many times.

I am in a way of searching for the solution.hope i can get here.

Thank you.

Comment: Definitely in-app purchase. I don't think Apple allows you to do it any other way if you're unlocking features within the app.

Comment: It really depends of the product. If the product is digital you can only use Apple's in app purchase. For physical products you can use any payment provider you wish.

Comment: @rckoenes is it so ? Check [PeoplePerHour](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/peopleperhour/id520499439?mt=8), app allows you to purchase digital goods within the application. Can you please highlight on that ? Just go to their Hourlies module in app and select any item which is definitely digital e.g. seo article

Comment: Well that is just luck, because Apple does not allow you to buy digital goods/services without their InAppPurchases. And just because some else is doing it does not mean that you will be allowed to. The chance is een great that if you make Apple aware of this thay will pull the other app from the store.

Comment: It is like a digital good obviously.So it can better to choose in-app purchase i hope? Thanks you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to Section 11 of the following document (Apple's guidelines for app review)
https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

You can sell physical goods using Paypal, Stripe etc. which provide iOS SDKs to integrate payments within your app. But for selling in-app content/subscriptions, you must use Apple's In-app purchase in which case you'll have to share 30% of your revenue with Apple.